# How to filter nested object array with dynamic multiple check boxes in AngularJS. OR with and Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I trying to build a product list based on multiple filters. I thought this should be very straight forward but it's not for me at least.

Here is the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/vufFfWyef3TwL6ofvniP?p=preview

Checkboxes are dynamically generated from respective model e.g. `sizes`, `colours`, `categories`. Subcategory checkbozes should perform 'OR' query but cross section it should perform 'AND' query.

basically something like

```
filter:{categories:selectedcategories1} || {categories:selectedcategories2} | filter:{categories:selectedsizes1} || {categories:selectedsizes2}
```

problem is generating these filters dynamically. I also tried with filter in controller as-

```
var tempArr = [{'categories':'selectedvalue1'}, {'categories':'selectedvalue2'}];
var OrFilterObjects = tempArr.join('||');
$scope.products = $filter('filter')($scope.products, OrFilterObjects, true);
```

But couldn't find a way to assign correct value for `OrFilterObjects`.

Now as latest attempt (which is in plunkr) I am trying to use a custom filter. It's also not returning OR result.

Right now I am using it as `productFilter:search.categories:'categories'` if it would have  returned OR result then I'd planned to use it as-

```
`productFilter:search.categories:'categories' | productFilter:search.colours:'colours' | productFilter:search.sizes:'sizes'`
```

Since I am here seeking help, it would be nice to have like `productFilter:search`.

I've spent considerable amount of time to find solution of this supposedly simple problem but most of examples use 'non-dynamic' checkboxes or flat objects.

May be I am thinking in wrong direction and there is a more elegant and simple Angular way for such scenarios. I would love to be directed towards any solution to similar solution where nested objects can be filtered with automated dynamically generated filters. Seems to me very generic use case for any shopping application but till now no luck getting there.

Comment: Why don't you use one object for your filter `seach = {categories: ["cat"], colour: ["red"], sizes: ["L"]}`. and your filter will use that object, you will not need to write 3 filters.

Comment: Well assuming I want to run OR filter on same section, e.g. 'categores' based on selected checkboxes. If 'men' and 'women' both are selected it should return items for 'men' and 'women' both.

filter should look like `$filter('filter')($scope.products, filter:{categories:'men'} || {categories:'women'}, true);`.

If I have array as `[{categories:'men'},{categories:'women'}]` and using it in filter with 'join', filter would look like, `$filter('filter')($scope.products, filter:{categories:'men'},{categories:'women'}, true);` which off course wouldn't work.

That's significance of ||.

Comment: I've removed that comment with joining arrays. Does that comments is for that search object?

Comment: no, for earlier comment.

Comment: @jcubic I am infact using `search` object in same fashion but checkbox models would be nested as `search{categories:{checkedkey:true}, colours:{checkedkey:true}}` even if I get checked values as array instead of object as suggested, how would it help? Problem is to dynamically pass these conditions.

Comment: you don't need to use model for data in search object. Just use ng-change and based on model push or remove element from `seach.categories` array. Checkbox Model in your case will be for UI only and based on that you build your object.

Comment: @jcubic even in that case how would I run OR filter I am difficulty with.

Comment: You don't need to run or filter at all, create one filter that will do all your filtering, you don't need more then one filter if all your options for filters are in one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to understand: this problem is not, by any definition, simple. You want to find a match based on a property of an object in an array which is a property of an object inside an input array you're supplying, not to mention [OR intra group] + [AND inter group] relations, search properties defined by either `.title` or `.name`, as well as criteria selection being completely dynamic. It's a complex problem.

Though it's a common scenario for shopping cart websites, I doubt that any web framework will have this kind of functionality built into its API. It's unfortunate but I don't think we can avoid writing the logic ourselves.

At any rate, since ultimately you want to just declare `productFilter:search`, here it is:

```
app.filter('productFilter', function($filter) {
    var helper = function(checklist, item, listName, search) {
        var count = 0;
        var result = false;
        angular.forEach(checklist, function(checked, checkboxName) {
            if (checked) {
                count++;
                var obj = {};
                obj[search] = checkboxName;
                result = result || ($filter('filter')(item[listName], obj, true).length > 0);
            }
        });
        return (count === 0) || result;
    };

    return function(input, definition) {
        var result = [];

        if (angular.isArray(input) && angular.isObject(definition)) {
            angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
                var matched = null;
                angular.forEach(definition, function(checklist, listName) {
                    var tmp;
                    if (listName !== 'colours') {
                        tmp = helper(checklist, item, listName, 'title');
                    } else{
                        tmp = helper(checklist, item, listName, 'name');
                    }
                    matched = (matched === null) ? tmp : matched && tmp;
                });
                if (matched) result.push(item);
            });
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

A couple of notes:

- How to use: `ng-repeat="product in products | productFilter:search"`.
- The filter only does some basic checks: `input` must be an array, and `definition` must be an object. If you need more, you may do so there.
- I would say that `*.name` is an exception to the rule (I assume that most of the criteria is defined by `*.title`). So, we handle that in `if/else`.
- The `count` variable in a `helper` function is used to track how many checked checkbox(es) we went through for a particular criteria group. If we went through none, it means that whole criteria group is *inactive*, and we just return `true`.
- It's a good design to create a `filter` that doesn't mutate the states of other objects outside it. That's why using `count` is better than calling `cleanObj()`. This is especially crucial when designing common components for other devs to use in a team: you want to minimize the element of surprise as much as possible.

Comment: I implemented your solution with few adjustments according to my need and it indeed worked. It's disheartening to know there is no ready-made solution for this. I am accepting it and thanks a ton for explaining me around solution. It would surely serve me as navigator. Thanks again. :)